# multiple [[collectd]] in influx.conf

Tags: linux, database

I have following `collectd` instance running in `influx.conf` file and everything is good, but now I want to setup another instance totally isolated with existing one how do I do that? And can I do following in `influx.conf` file?

```
[[collectd]]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = "0.0.0.0:8096"
  database = "database-1"

[[collectd]]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = "0.0.0.0:8097"
  database = "database-2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/supported_protocols/collectd/), you should be able to use multiple CollectD input instances just like you specified above.

## Edit

Your configuration misses `security-level` and probably more options:

```
run: invalid collectd config: Invalid security level. To generate a valid configuration file run `influxd config > influxdb.generated.conf`
```

This works for me with even 3 `collectd` instances configured like this:

```
[[collectd]]
  enabled = true 
  bind-address = ":25826"
  database = "collectd-1"
  retention-policy = ""
  batch-size = 5000
  batch-pending = 10
  batch-timeout = "10s"
  read-buffer = 0
  typesdb = "/usr/share/collectd/types.db"
  security-level = "none"
  auth-file = "/etc/collectd/auth_file"
  parse-multivalue-plugin = "split"

[[collectd]]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":25827"
  database = "collectd-2"
  retention-policy = ""
  batch-size = 5000
  batch-pending = 10
  batch-timeout = "10s"
  read-buffer = 0
  typesdb = "/usr/share/collectd/types.db"
  security-level = "none"
  auth-file = "/etc/collectd/auth_file"
  parse-multivalue-plugin = "split"

[[collectd]]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":25828"
  database = "collectd-3"
  retention-policy = ""
  batch-size = 5000
  batch-pending = 10
  batch-timeout = "10s"
  read-buffer = 0
  typesdb = "/usr/share/collectd/types.db"
  security-level = "none"
  auth-file = "/etc/collectd/auth_file"
  parse-multivalue-plugin = "split"
```

```
$ docker run -p 8086:8086 -v $PWD/influxdb.conf:/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf:ro -v $PWD/types.db:/usr/share/collectd/types.db influxdb -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
[...]
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.750638Z lvl=info msg="Starting collectd service" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000 service=collectd
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.750653Z lvl=info msg="Loading types from file" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000 service=collectd path=/usr/share/collectd/types.db
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.754041Z lvl=info msg="Listening on UDP" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000 service=collectd addr=[::]:25826
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.754405Z lvl=info msg="Starting collectd service" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000 service=collectd
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.754436Z lvl=info msg="Loading types from file" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000 service=collectd path=/usr/share/collectd/types.db
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.759837Z lvl=info msg="Listening on UDP" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000 service=collectd addr=[::]:25827
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.760296Z lvl=info msg="Starting collectd service" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000 service=collectd
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.760321Z lvl=info msg="Loading types from file" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000 service=collectd path=/usr/share/collectd/types.db
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.763582Z lvl=info msg="Listening on UDP" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000 service=collectd addr=[::]:25828
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.764035Z lvl=info msg="Sending usage statistics to usage.influxdata.com" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000
ts=2019-08-20T14:23:49.764091Z lvl=info msg="Listening for signals" log_id=0HNrR~ZG000
```

Comment: Not working, i have tired my example :(  it totally stopped working when i add two instance, if i remove one it works.

Comment: any error message?

Comment: check this thread out. https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4405  folks saying you can't do that.

Comment: that's old and as far as I see, would've changed so far, influx documentation would suggest IMO you should be able to configure multiple. check logs for errors, maybe something is misconfigured?

Comment: @Satish, see my edit, you're missing `security-level` from the configuration.

Comment: You are right i was getting `security-level` error so i have copy paste your config sample and now i am getting this error `run: invalid collectd config: Invalid value for parse-multivalue-plugin. Valid options are "split" and "join".`  even i have that option in config

Comment: why do you have `enabled = false ` ?

Comment: sorry, that was my bad, copied over wrong config. it works for me with enabled. what's your influx version?

Comment: nevermind... i figured it out.. my old instance was missing `parse-multivalue-plugin` option, look like when you have more than two instance you need all the options in both instance. older and newer.. Thank you so much!!!